# Search for file in c#

Tags: c#

I wanted to search for files in c# begin with a string.
I followed the code in the internet

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "c*");
```

but instead of finding `"c"`, I want to find files contains a string (i mean the file name for example contain.txt and contain.pdf both has "contain") i created. Here is my code

```
string filetofind;
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", filetofind + "*");
```

but it just not working, is there anyway else?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What does `filetofind` look like? And you said _"contains"_, so you probably meant `"*" + filetofin + "*"`. Your current version only looks for file that _start_ with `filetofind`.

Comment: Do you look for file **names** that contain `filetofind` or do you really mean the file _content_?

Comment: I mean the name, i tried filetofind + "*" and there is a file started with that string but it still not found

Comment: @NguyễnNgọcAnh - Then you are not correctly matching the characters. Can you post the actual names of the files you are searching among and the text you are searching for?

Comment: it is the string that user input. In my case testing it is 696969. I created a file 696969.txt but the code doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

If

> I want to find files **contains a string** i created

means you want to check file's *content* (not *name*) You have to *load* the file, e.g. (assuming `stringToFind` doesn't have line breaks)

```
 string[] dirs = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt");              // all txt files (put the right wildcard)
   .Where(file => File                             
      .ReadLines(file)                            // with at least one line
      .Any(line => line.Contains(stringToFind)))  // which contains stringToFind
   .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** In case you want files' *names* which contain `c`, e.g. `"mycode.txt"`, `"Constraints.dat"` etc. (but not `"demo.com"` since `c` is in the file's *extension*); you can try `*c*.*` wild card: file name contains `c` with any extension:

```
  string[] dirs = Directory
    .GetFiles(@"c:\", $"*{filetofind}*.*");
```

In case of *elaborated* condition, when standard *wildcard* in not enough, just add `Where`:

```
 string[] dirs = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.*")
   .Where(path => Your_Condition(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
   .ToArray();
```

For instance, let's test file name for *small* (not *capital*) letter `c`

```
 string[] dirs = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.*")
   .Where(path => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).Contains('c'))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry i mean file name

Comment: @Nguyễn Ngọc Anh: in case of *file name* you have to change the wild card a bit; if actual condition is complex enough to be beyond wildcard, you have to put `Where` with the required condition.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I know this is an old thread! But in your very first piece of code, what if I wanted to search string into a pdf file and not in a text file.. Something like that of windows search - `File contents`. I have posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548502/file-content-search-c-sharp

Comment: @ Ashish Srivastava: in case of *pdf* file, you can't just put `File.ReadLines(file)` and get all lines; yo have to *parse* it.

Answer (score 3):

To find files where the file name contains "foo", use

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\dir", "*foo*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

To find files where the text content contains "foo" use:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\dir", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => File.ReadAllText(f).Contains("foo"));
```

This should work, but it will read the entire file as text until you stop enumerating the list of files, so you might want to filter the file list search pattern before reading them. You could also write your own method to inspect each file rather than reading the entire thing into memory for every file.

Substitute `SearchOption.AllDirectories` for `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` if you only want to search that directory, and not recursively search subdirectories.

Comment: what if "foo" is a string. can i use "*" + foo + "*"?

Comment: The final string passed to `EnumerateFiles` is a file search pattern, so that would be `"*"+foo+"*"`.  When searching inside content, it's using `string.Contains` so you would just do `.Contains(foo)`.

Answer (score -1):

if the file you want find starts with "filetofind" then code is correct. But if "filetofind" comes somewhere between the complete file name then your code must change to

```
string filetofind;
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*filetofind*");
```